# Is there a way to control the space between lines in an eqnarray environment?

Tags: equations, two-column

I'm writing a piece using two columns and some equations are just too big to fit properly so I have to break them down into several lines. The final result, however is not pleasing. The lines get too cloose to each other. Is there a way to solve this?

This is an equation with the problem I'm talking about:

```
 \begin{eqnarray}
E_{_{\rm INC}} = E_{_0}\,\sqrt{\frac{\displaystyle w}{\displaystyle wz(z)}}\,\exp\left[\frac{\displaystyle -y^{^2}}{\displaystyle wz^{^2}(z)}\right] {\nonumber} \\
{\times} \exp\left[i\left( k\,z+k\,\frac{y^{^2}}{2\,R(z)}-\frac{1}{2}\,\zeta(z) \right)\right]
\end{eqnarray}
```

Thank you very much guys. A lot of helpful tips! (I'm writting this here so I can thak you all at once)

Comment: note that `eqnarray` is really deprecated, better to use `align` from `amsmath` and `\rm` shouldn't be used in latex, especially not in math mode.

Comment: If you do use `eqnarray` every row has to have two `&` (`&=&` usually) but your example has none. also why the double subscript?? `E_{_0}`

Comment: What does the & symbol do? I know I can use it to align = symbols in several lines but in this case it is just one long expression.

Is \mathrm ok? What is the problem it \rm in math mode?

The double subscript is there to make the 0 smaller.

Comment: `eqnarray` (if it is used at all is an _alignment_ construct if you don't use the alignment markers then anything it produces is essentially just accidental, the `_{_` is  wrong (and the `z^{^2` is almost unreadable with the 2 floating off somewhere far from the base. `\rm` is not defined _at all_ in the latex format (since latex2e came out in 1993)  some classes including `article` define it as a compatibility for old documents from the 1980s but using it this century is odd.

Comment: I see. Thank you, David. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `eqnarray`. Never.

You should instead use `split`, for this application.

I also fixed a few errors; for instance removed some wrong `\,` (keeping others that are good); also `y^{^2}` is wrong.

Don't use `\rm`, but `\mathrm` as shown below.

You judge which one is better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Wrong display with \texttt{eqnarray}
 \begin{eqnarray}
E_{_{\rm INC}} = E_{_0}\,\sqrt{\frac{\displaystyle w}{\displaystyle wz(z)}}\,\exp\left[\frac{\displaystyle -y^{^2}}{\displaystyle wz^{^2}(z)}\right] {\nonumber} \\
{\times} \exp\left[i\left( k\,z+k\,\frac{y^{^2}}{2\,R(z)}-\frac{1}{2}\,\zeta(z) \right)\right]
\end{eqnarray}
and better one with \texttt{split} and several fixes
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E_{\mathrm{INC}} 
  &= E_{0}\,\sqrt{\frac{w}{wz(z)}}\,\exp\left[\frac{-y^{2}}{wz^{2}(z)}\right] \\[1ex]
  &\qquad \times \exp\left[i\left( kz+k\frac{y^{2}}{2R(z)}-\frac{1}{2}\zeta(z) \right)\right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the better display in context in a two column document

[image]

The advantage of using `split` is that you can decide whether split equations have the number in the middle or at the bottom line level. For this you add the `tbtags` options to `amsmath`:

```
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
```

Here's the result

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Mostly the spacing was poor because of the markup such as `y^{^2}` which produces very misplaced superscripts, fixing that and using `amsmath` produces better spacing already but as shown in the third example you can separate the lines by a `\jot` or a specific length such as `5pt` if you prefer.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

one
 \begin{eqnarray}
E_{_{\rm INC}} = E_{_0}\,\sqrt{\frac{\displaystyle w}{\displaystyle wz(z)}}\,\exp\left[\frac{\displaystyle -y^{^2}}{\displaystyle wz^{^2}(z)}\right] {\nonumber} \\
{\times} \exp\left[i\left( k\,z+k\,\frac{y^{^2}}{2\,R(z)}-\frac{1}{2}\,\zeta(z) \right)\right]
\end{eqnarray}


two
 \begin{multline}
E_{\mathrm{INC}} = E_{0}\,\sqrt{\frac{w}{wz(z)}}\,
\exp\Bigl[\frac{-y^{2}}{wz^{2}(z)}\Bigr]  \\
\times \exp\Bigl[i\bigl( k\,z+k\,\frac{y^{2}}{2\,R(z)}-\frac{1}{2}\,\zeta(z) \bigr)\Bigr]
\end{multline}

three
 \begin{multline}
E_{\mathrm{INC}} = E_{0}\,\sqrt{\frac{w}{wz(z)}}\,
\exp\Bigl[\frac{-y^{2}}{wz^{2}(z)}\Bigr]  \\[\jot]
\times \exp\Bigl[i\bigl( k\,z+k\,\frac{y^{2}}{2\,R(z)}-\frac{1}{2}\,\zeta(z) \bigr)\Bigr]
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `\\` has an optional argument. For example `\\[12pt]`  enlarges the distance by 12 pt. (In fact, it is more subtle, but it is good for first approximation).

This a general parameter of `\\`. In our case:

1. `eqnarray` has many disadvantages, hence using other tools, e.g. from `amsmath` package, is recommended.
2. If used, `eqnarray` is a 3-column structure, so adding the rest of line right of position of `=` would be better.
3. `\displaystyle` should be rather used before `\frac`, or rather `\dfrac` from `amsmath` can be used.